# T-SQL to XMl nested and split

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, split

I am stuck with creating XML Data out of a T-SQl query:

here is the query:

```
(Select case when pc.CASE_TYPE_ID = 4 then prt.DESIGNATED_COUNTRYS end as "countries"
for xml path ('countries'), type )
,(Select case when pc.CASE_TYPE_ID = 4 then prt.classes end as classes
for xml path ('countries'), type )


from PAT_REPORT_TABLE prt join pat_case pc on pc.case_id = prt.case_id
for XML PATH('ip_row'),type, ROOT ('ip_data')
```

the result looks like :

```
<ip_data>
  <ip_row>
    <countries>
      <countries>AT, BX, CH, CS, DE, EG, FI, FR, HU, IT, MA, RO</countries>
    </countries>
    <classes>
      <classes>01, 04</classes>
   </classes>
  </ip_row>
</ip_data>
```

but i need the countries and classes in separate rows.
So my desired result should be:

```
<ip_data>
  <ip_row>
    <countries>
      <country>AT</country>
      <country>BX</country>
      <country>CH</country>
      <country>CS</country>
      <country>DE</country>
      <country>EG</country>
      <country>FI</country>
      <country>FR</country>
      <country>HU</country>
    </countries>
    <classes>
      <class>01</class>
      <class>04</class>
    </classes>
  </ip_row>
</ip_data>
```

How Do i split this up ?

Comment: What data type and content do you find for column `DESIGNATED_COUNTRYS `? Please try to set up a [mcve] (*stand alone solution with DDL and INSERTs, at least some sample data and the expected output for this).

Comment: Just as @Shnugo pointed out, Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are after is this (note the `,''` after each of the `CASE` expressions), however, without sample data this is impossible to test;

```sql
SELECT {...,} --Your statement was missing a starting SELECT, not sure if there are prior columns too
       (SELECT CASE WHEN PC.CASE_TYPE_ID = 4 THEN PRT.DESIGNATED_COUNTRYS END AS countries,''
        FOR XML PATH ('countries'), TYPE ),
        (SELECT CASE WHEN PC.CASE_TYPE_ID = 4 THEN PRT.CLASSES END AS classes,''
         FOR XML PATH ('countries'), TYPE )
FROM PAT_REPORT_TABLE prt
     JOIN pat_case pc ON pc.case_id = prt.case_id
FOR XML PATH('ip_row'),TYPE, ROOT ('ip_data');
```